# heathen humanitarians

Tags: phrases

In The Oracle of the Dog story by G. K. Chesterton,

The Father Brown was talking angrily to someone who was thinking that the dog identified the killer in a murder, because it was barking at him madly, saying: "So the dog denounced him, did he? The oracle of the dog condemned him. Did you see what birds were flying, and are you sure whether they were on the right hand or the left? Did you consult the augurs about the sacrifices? Surely you didn’t omit to cut open the dog and examine his entrails. That is the sort of scientific test you **heathen humanitarians** seem to trust when you are thinking of taking away the life and honour of a man.

What's meant here by **heathen humanitarians**?

Comment: Could we trouble you to look up each word and get back to us? Usually, humanitarians are nice, not heathens.

Comment: And that's what confuses me!

Comment: [**heathen**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heathen) *- an uncivilized or irreligious person*, [**humanitarian**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/humanitarian) *- (a person who is) involved in or connected with improving people's lives and reducing suffering.* You can make up your own mind whether Chesterton (or Father Brown) disapproves of heathens and/or humanitarians.

Comment: I'm guessing the usage is somewhat facetious, though I'm not familiar enough with Chesterton's style to know with any certainty or explain precisely what was intended to be conveyed.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin Did you mean to say that humanitarians are _usually_ not heathens, or that the heathens are _usually_ not nice? I've known the unusual ones in either case.

Answer (score 5):

The words mean what you think they mean, with some nuance.  Heathen here means secular, while humanitarian refers to people who help others. It is somewhat pejorative here however, in the sense that Chesterton views them as people who think they know better due to their secular knowledge and are overly willing to interfere with others.  He is questioning their knowledge and especially their willingness to interfere in others life because of it.

Comment: At the risk of a little nitpick, "heathen" doesn't mean "secular" it means "not Christian".

Comment: @DJClayworth I don't think the usual meaning of "heathen" is that broad. It's closer to "pagan". In particular, I don't think it applies to Jews.

Comment: That makes more sense, thank you so much

Comment: @AndreasBlass On reflection, yes you are right. It wouldn't include Jews and probably not complete atheists

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make any sense to me with the current meaning of *humanitarian*.

I believe it is intended in the sense of the OED's definition 2:

> 2. Chiefly with capital initial. A person who professes a humanistic religion, esp. an adherent of the socialist religious ideas of Pierre
>      Leroux (1797–1871). Cf. humanism *n*. 5. Now *historical*.

In other words, roughly what a modern writer would call a *humanist*.

Comment: No, if you’re familiar with Chesterton it is clear that the standard definition of humanitarian is what he meant.

Comment: The current meaning of "vegetarian" is someone who only eats vegetables...

Answer (score -1):

Quite simply, the phrase heathen humanitarian is an oxymoron. Chesterton is using the oxymoron sarcastically. I'm sure that his character, Father Brown, is saying in effect,

> "You would *like to think* you are scientific humanitarians, but *in reality* you are no better than superstitious heathens, thinking the barking of a dog carries more weight than the sacredness of a person's life and reputation."